# Are running apps slowing down Android phones?

Tags: performance, task-management

When my phone (Xperia J) is getting slow I'll go to *Setting→Apps*, select *running apps*, and delete everything in there. Then I go back to the homescreen and I notice that my phone is faster.

So is running apps making my phone slow or it is just a coincident?

Answer (score 3):

While this might appear to temporarily "speed up" your device, this kind of "Chuck Norris Roundhouse Kick" is rather contra-productive for the system, especially for two things:

1. your battery load
2. time to access one of the killed apps again

Android usually does a good job managing [ram](/questions/tagged/ram). But some apps sometimes make it hard to do so (mostly by not behaving properly: hogging lots of RAM and trying to "stay alive" even if the user wishes them to quit). So to have the same "speed-up feeling" without the nasty side-effects, you'd better identify those bad-behaving apps which you killed *along* the others (like the wild-west saying: "Kill'em all and let the Lord sort out the bad from the good").

I've just added two tags to your question. You might wish to consult their tag-wikis and most frequented questions for more details. To do so, simply click them (or hover your mouse over them and select the links to "info" for the tag-wiki, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

The concept is the same with a PC. If you have too many programs running at the same time on your computer, the you will notice that it becomes slow or sluggish over time.

AND if you look at the Xperia J's specs, it only has a single-core processor. So, you can't really expect it to run as snappy as a Samsung Galaxy S4 which has a quad-core processor.

Comment: It's not really helpful to compare a mid-range phone with the latest top-of-the-range handset. This answer reads as "it's your fault for not spending more money on a higher spec phone" rather than helping the OP in any way.